# OpenCV-Python: img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to write a save image function. The below code is expected to create a copy of the original image as saved-test-image.jpg.

```
originalImage = "test-image.jpg"
savedImage = cv2.imwrite("saved-test-image.jpg",originalImage)
```

The execution of the lines gives the follwing back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UnitTest.py", line 159, in test_save_and_delete_image
    savedImage = cv2.imwrite('unittest-images/saved-test-image.jpg', originalImage)
TypeError: img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

What needs to be changed here?

Comment: You should first `imread(..)` the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well `opencv` is right, you save `originalImage`, but `originalImage` is a string (the filename, your first line).

You need to **`cv2.imread(..)` your image into a numpy array** first:

```
originalImage = cv2.imread("test-image.jpg")
savedImage = cv2.imwrite("saved-test-image.jpg",originalImage)
```

If you simply want to copy an image file however, there is no need to load it into memory, you can simply *copy the file*, without using opencv:

```
from shutil import copyfile

originalImage = "test-image.jpg"
copyfile(originalImage,"saved-test-image.jpg")
```

In this case, it will simply copy the file - regardless what its content is - so even if it is a corrupt image, or not an image at all, it will be copied.